# Installing Hyper-V 2012 R2 to USB gives INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, usb-flash-drive, usb-boot

I have created a bootable USB flash drive of Windows Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 Core following the guides [here](http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/installing-and-running-hyper-v-from-a-usb-stick/) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj733589.aspx). When I boot my desktop PC from the USB drive it boots up fine (after a while) and I can log in. When I put the USB drive in my server tower and try and boot from USB, I get this error:

`INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE`

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Create a new USB drive for your server. Don't try to boot one on your server that was already booted from your desktop.

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried that and got the same problem on the server with a fresh USB installation. Afterwards I put the USB in my desktop as a test and it could boot from it fine. I also tried using the Hyper-V 2012 (not R2) image and the server could boot from USB with that fine, but I want 2012 R2... Any other ideas?

Comment: @MarkAllison AFAIK, when you install an OS on a physical server, you use an installation disk (provided by the manufacturer), which contains a preinstallation-environment with the required drivers for booting the server. I think you'll need to do a regular installation first on your server, and then copy it to a vhd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never solved this and due to lack of time, just decided to put in a hard drive and install to that instead of trying to boot from USB. I did notice that when I had successfully booted from USB using Windows Server 2012 that performance of the host (not guests) was quite bad. Loading powershell for example took a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the drivers for your server's storage subsystem to your USB flash drive's image of Windows.  See dism.exe for the easiest way to do that.